# Java Base64 MIME decoding/encoding throws away delimiters

Tags: java, scala, base64

I have a Base64-encoded string that looks like `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K"`. I'm trying to decode it back to binary and later encode it again into Base64 using `java.util.Base64`. Strangely, after decoding and encoding again, I would lose the delimiters and get back `"dataimage/pngbase64iVBORw0I="`.

This is how I do the decoding and encoding (written in Scala, but you get the idea):

```
import java.util.Base64

val b64mime = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K"

val decoder = Base64.getMimeDecoder
val encoder = Base64.getMimeEncoder

println(encoder.encodeToString(decoder.decode(b64mime)))
```

Here is an example: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/TJY7eeg/0

This also happens with `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`. What am I doing wrong? Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The string you are trying to deal with looks like an example of a "data:" URL as specified in [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397)

The correct way to deal with one of these is parse it into its components, and then decode *only* the component that is base64 encoded.  Here is the syntax

```
   dataurl    := "data:" [ mediatype ] [ ";base64" ] "," data
   mediatype  := [ type "/" subtype ] *( ";" parameter )
   data       := *urlchar
   parameter  := attribute "=" value
```

So this says that everything up to the comma in your example is non-base64 data.  You cannot simply treat the whole string as base64 because it contains characters that are not valid in any standard variant of the base64 encoding scheme.

This Q&A talks about RFC 2397 parsers in Java:

- [Any RFC 2397 Data URI Parser for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353552/any-rfc-2397-data-uri-parser-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

Base64 doesnt have those characters in it. It looks like the decoder is ignoring those invalid characters.

```
@ decoder.decode(";") 
res10: Array[Byte] = Array()
```

However if you just decode the last part you get what you want.

```
@ decoder.decode("iVBORw0K") 
res9: Array[Byte] = Array(-119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10)
@ encoder.encodeToString(res9) 
res12: String = "iVBORw0K"
```